Cannot synchronize blockchain because of a "bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent, CheckTxInputs: inputs missing/spent"
a node is synchronizing the blockchain and is stucked for a problem on a specific block:
ERROR: ConnectBlock: Consensus::CheckTxInputs: b39bfb750ee35530d8bc7cc4c3d52860e2e292139532afa487e7a70c4cec748f, bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent, CheckTxInputs: inputs missing/spent
InvalidChainFound: invalid block=0000000000000000000450ac9a98c292af2ad818e5b24251751b14972cb9cbb4  height=665135  log2_work=92.575896  date=2021-01-08T15:19:44Z
InvalidChainFound:  current best=00000000000000000006c27ff60225c9474705273b88fd943d6485ca38d5d061  height=665134  log2_work=92.575880  date=2021-01-08T15:14:01Z
ERROR: ConnectTip: ConnectBlock 0000000000000000000450ac9a98c292af2ad818e5b24251751b14972cb9cbb4 failed, bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent, CheckTxInputs: inputs missing/spent
InvalidChainFound: invalid block=0000000000000000000b557216ea30509bd5e38eac34dea9d8d08fb168901c3e  height=665166  log2_work=92.576379  date=2021-01-08T20:37:05Z
InvalidChainFound:  current best=00000000000000000006c27ff60225c9474705273b88fd943d6485ca38d5d061  height=665134  log2_work=92.575880  date=2021-01-08T15:14:01Z

It goes on with Pre-synchronizing blockheaders, height: ... until above 96.00% and then restart from the failed block.
I tried to lauunch the "reconsider" command with the hash of the block, but I had no success.
Is there a way to solve this problem without redownloading the entire blockchain from the start, please?
Thank you in advance.
